# Unable to highlight text/variable in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My Eclipse IDE wouldn't highlight similar text/variable in Java code, till yesterday it was working fine. Today if I click on a variable inside a class it would not highlight same variable present elsewhere in class. Should I enable any thing in IDE?

Comment: Just out of interest why are you using eclipse over NetBeans?  I'm new to Java and am currently deciding on which to use and am leaning to NetBeans.

Comment: I am working on Android , hence Eclipse

Answer (score 17):

Please check

1. 'Toggle Mark Occurrences' enabled (It is in the tool bar or use shortcut Alt + Shift + O).
2. Checks the preference.
   Go to 'Preference' then navigate to 'General --> Editor --> Text Editors --> Annotations --> Occurrences'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I was trying new keyboard shortcuts and something toggled my Mark Occurrences. I was confused but now this solved my issue.

Comment: On Mac, it's `alt` + `cmd` + `o`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, I had to toggle mark occurrences alt+shift+o. If any one faces this issue you can try this to fix it.

Comment: Looks like you found the answer already :)

Comment: To avoid the issue in the future you could unbind alt+shift+o as I assume this issue occured as you accidentally pressed alt+shift+o without realizing that is was a key binding.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Preference - > Annotations - Occurrences Text as checkbox list value should have selected Highlighted.